# Warnings running the GLPaint sample

Tags: xcode, ios5, warnings

I've looked at other questions related to the `GLPaint` sample from Apple. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I am getting these warnings:

```
Unused parameter 'touches'
Unused parameter 'touches'
Unused parameter 'touches'
Unused parameter 'touches'
Unused parameter 'event'

Unused parameter 'motion'
Unused parameter 'event'
Unused parameter 'event'
Unused parameter 'motion'
Unused parameter 'event'
Unused parameter 'sender'
```

An example of where they are, are in the `PaintingView.m` file, and the method is:

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

The sample runs but as I modify it to my needs, I'd like to understand what these mean, and how to fix them.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning

> Unused parameter 'touches'

Means that the parameter `touches` was not used inside the method. For example:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     // some code where the parameter touches is not used
}
```

Finally, note that you can deactivate these warnings (which is the default setup) by changing the value highlighted in the following screenshot to **NO**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. They are used elsewhere. If I remove them (comment them), I get errors. If you're sure it's ok to reset the debug parameters, I'll go ahead. Thanks for answering so quickly.

Comment: Personally, I like having warnings for unused values and variables but not for unused parameters, because its frequent to have method implementations where some parameters are not used.